# How to get Kerberos tickets in sync with OS X password changes?

Tags: mac-osx, kerberos, mac-osx-server, opendirectory, heimdal

I've traced an issue that's been plaguing us down to a "simple" problem:

Kerberos tickets are not syncing with OS X Open Directory password changes.

Another way to put this:

Expired/expiring ticket renewal requests are being signed with old keys until the machine is rebooted.

How can I get these back in sync?